# Short story where 2 zombies are in love

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for author or book that had a short story about 2 zombies in love. There is one part that I really remember. The 2 zombies bit each other as a show of affection and as the female zombie bites the male on the neck a bunch of roaches comes gushing out of the wound. There were a lot of good stories in this book.

Any ideas?

Comment: Were all the stories in the book about zombies? Do you remember any other of the stories? How old is the book?

Answer (score 6):

The story is [Eat Me](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48326) by Robert R. McCammon, so I'd guess the anthology is [Zombies Encounters with the Hungry Dead](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1164655) edited by John Skipp.

[image: Zombies]

The scene you remember is:

> Brenda's teeth closed on the back of Jim's neck, crunching through the dry flesh. Her eyes closed in rapture as Jim ate the rest of the fingers on her left hand-and suddenly there was a new sensation, a scurrying around her lips. The love wound on Jim's neck was erupting small yellow roaches, like gold coins spilling from a bag, and Jim's itching subsided. He cried out, his face burrowing into Brenda's abdominal cavity.

Comment: @LSerni I had to reread it to write this answer and ... well ... *ewwww* :-)